# Почему не сортируется массив arrBySelect по клику на <th class="th">? Как исправить?

Tags: javascript

````
select.onchange = function createTBody(){
        message.style = 'display: none';
        theadtr.innerHTML = `<th class="th">Country name</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>World region</th>
        <th>Languages</th>
        <th class="th">Area</th>
        <th>Flag</th>`  
        let arrBySelect;
     let selectValue = select.value;
         langArr.forEach( function(lang) {      
            if (lang === selectValue)   {
                arrBySelect = externalService.getCountryListByLanguage(selectValue)
            } 
        })
        regArr.forEach( function(reg) {     
            if (reg === selectValue)    {
                arrBySelect = externalService.getCountryListByRegion(selectValue)
            } 
        })
        
        let th = document.querySelectorAll('.th')    
     th.forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (e) => {        
             if(e.target.classList.contains('th')) {
                     th.classList.remove('th')
                     th.classList.add('thReverse')
                     console.log(arrBySelect)
                     arrBySelect.sort((a, b) => b > a ? 1 : -1);
                } else {
                     th.classList.remove('thReverse')
                     th.classList.add('th')
                     arrBySelect.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)                  
             }
         }))

     tbody.innerHTML = arrBySelect.map((country) => 
    ` <tr>
      <td>${country.name}</td>
    <td>${country.capital}</td>
    <td>${country.region}</td>
    <td>${getLanguages(country.languages)}</td>
    <td>${country.area}</td>
    <td><img src="${country.flagURL}"></td>
        </tr> `
   ).join('')    

    }
    ```
````

Comment: Вам стОит научиться более полно и корректно описывать проблему и задавать вопрос. Потому что человечество пока не на столько развито, чтобы понимать те мысли, что у вас в голове и знать, что вы у себя там такое делаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Человечество - возможно, но нам-то все понятно.

Comment: Слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы есть знак "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в массиве - набор объектов-стран, что Вы тут `b < a ?` сравниваете?

```
theadtr.innerHTML = `<th class="th" data-sortfield="name">Country name</th> ...`
...
b[th.dataset.sortfield] < a[th.dataset.sortfield] ? ...
```